# Transform sequences of values in a column to rows for a timeseries of events in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am working with a timeseries with certain events that occur with a given order:  `A->B->C->D` and I want to create a new `DataFrame` having as columns the time of these events, namely from the `DataFrame` `old_df`:

```
    ev_type       ev_time
1     W      2012-05-27 02:06:01
2     A      2012-05-28 02:06:01
3     B      2012-05-28 03:06:01
4     C      2012-05-28 04:06:01
5     D      2012-05-28 02:06:03
6     K      2012-05-28 02:06:01
...   ...    ...................
60000 D      2016-01-01 01:01:01
```

I'd like to get `df`:

```
              A_time               B_time               C_time                D_time
1       2012-05-28 02:06:01  2012-05-28 03:06:01  2012-05-28 04:06:01  2012-05-28 04:06:01
...             ....             ....               ....                    ....
5000    2015-05-28 02:06:01  2015-06-28 02:06:01 2015-07-28 02:06:01 2015-08-28 02:06:01
```

What I did is

```
A_events = old_df.evtype == 'A'
df = old_df[A_events ].ev_time.to_frame()
df.rename(columns={"ev_time":"A_time"},inplace=True)
df.join(old_df[A_events.shift(1).fillna(False)].ev_time.shift(-1),axis=1)
```

But this last line doesn't work because it doesn't change the index. The best I could get is

```
     A_time               B_time 
2  2012-05-28 02:06:01    NaT
3   NaT                  2012-05-28 03:06:01
```

How can I align the two Series? Or are there better strategies to extract a sequence of event or a  pattern from a pandas dataframe?

### EDIT

Following the code suggested by  @Stefan below, a generator for my data is

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ev_type': np.random.choice(list("ABCDWK"), size=100,replace=True), 'ev_time': pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2016,1,1),freq='M', periods=100)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whoever visits this question looking for a similar issue, here I report how I did solve it. I am not sure it is the most pythonic/memory efficient way to look for event sequences...

To generate the data I used the code suggested by Stefan

```
size_of_df = 10000
df_old = pd.DataFrame(data={'ev_type': np.random.choice(list("ABCDWK"), size=size_of_df,replace=True), 'ev_time': pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2016,1,1),freq='h', periods=size_of_df)})
```

The sequence doesn't appear often, so the length of the df has to be big enough (or you have to be luck)

```
df_old.head(5)

              ev_time ev_type
0 2016-01-01 00:00:00       D
1 2016-01-01 01:00:00       D
2 2016-01-01 02:00:00       A
3 2016-01-01 03:00:00       C
4 2016-01-01 04:00:00       W
```

Then, I shifted the dataframe and glued it, to get all events in a row

```
sequence = "ABCD"
evnt = pd.concat([df_old.shift(-ix) for ix,let in enumerate(list(sequence))],axis=1,keys=list(sequence))
```

and looked for the sequence

```
tmp_evt = evnt.xs('ev_type',level=1,axis=1)
tmp_seq = tmp_evt.apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(),axis=1)
tmp_seq.head()

0    DDAC
1    DACW
2    ACWK
3    CWKD
4    WKDA
dtype: object

bool_sequence = tmp_seq == 'ABCD'
col_name=dict(zip(list(sequence),[ let +   "_time" for let in list(sequence)]))
evnt[bool_sequence].xs('ev_time',level=1,axis=1).rename(columns=col_name).head()


                  A_time              B_time              C_time  \
1648 2016-03-09 16:00:00 2016-03-09 17:00:00 2016-03-09 18:00:00   
2913 2016-05-01 09:00:00 2016-05-01 10:00:00 2016-05-01 11:00:00   
3803 2016-06-07 11:00:00 2016-06-07 12:00:00 2016-06-07 13:00:00   
3879 2016-06-10 15:00:00 2016-06-10 16:00:00 2016-06-10 17:00:00   
4730 2016-07-16 02:00:00 2016-07-16 03:00:00 2016-07-16 04:00:00   

                  D_time  
1648 2016-03-09 19:00:00  
2913 2016-05-01 12:00:00  
3803 2016-06-07 14:00:00  
3879 2016-06-10 18:00:00  
4730 2016-07-16 05:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

After clarifying the question, you could:

Sample data:

```
size = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ev_type': np.random.choice(list("ABCDWK"), size=size, replace=True),
                        'ev_time': pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2016, 1, 1), freq='Min', periods=size)})


seq = 'ABCD'
df['sequence'] = list(range(len(seq))) * int((size/len(seq)))
df = df.set_index('sequence', append=True).unstack().fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill').drop_duplicates()
df['ev_type'] = df.loc[:, 'ev_type'].sum(axis=1)
df.loc[df[('ev_type', 0)] == 'ABCD'].loc[:, 'ev_time'].rename(columns={c: seq[c] for c in df.loc[:, 'ev_time'].columns})
```

to get:

```
sequence                   A                   B                   C  \
1197     2016-01-01 19:56:00 2016-01-01 19:57:00 2016-01-01 19:54:00   
1198     2016-01-01 19:56:00 2016-01-01 19:57:00 2016-01-01 19:58:00   
2498     2016-01-02 17:36:00 2016-01-02 17:37:00 2016-01-02 17:38:00   
4269     2016-01-03 23:08:00 2016-01-03 23:09:00 2016-01-03 23:06:00   
4946     2016-01-04 10:24:00 2016-01-04 10:25:00 2016-01-04 10:26:00   
4947     2016-01-04 10:24:00 2016-01-04 10:25:00 2016-01-04 10:26:00   
5476     2016-01-04 19:16:00 2016-01-04 19:13:00 2016-01-04 19:14:00   
6808     2016-01-05 17:28:00 2016-01-05 17:25:00 2016-01-05 17:26:00   
6809     2016-01-05 17:28:00 2016-01-05 17:29:00 2016-01-05 17:26:00   
6810     2016-01-05 17:28:00 2016-01-05 17:29:00 2016-01-05 17:30:00   
6811     2016-01-05 17:28:00 2016-01-05 17:29:00 2016-01-05 17:30:00   

sequence                   D  
1197     2016-01-01 19:55:00  
1198     2016-01-01 19:55:00  
2498     2016-01-02 17:35:00  
4269     2016-01-03 23:07:00  
4946     2016-01-04 10:23:00  
4947     2016-01-04 10:27:00  
5476     2016-01-04 19:15:00  
6808     2016-01-05 17:27:00  
6809     2016-01-05 17:27:00  
6810     2016-01-05 17:27:00  
6811     2016-01-05 17:31:00
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry I was not clear in my question. I'm going to edit it. The problem is that the number of rows are more then 60k, and the pattern is going to be repeated over 5k times. So, for sure, I cannot do `set_index('ev_type')`

Comment: This do something quite different from what I would like. In fact, it select arbitrarily the first D and then the first C and so on without looking for the exact sequence `A->B->C->D` that has to happend one after the other, as in the example.

Comment: I don't understand. The sample data are indeed randomly generated. I could just repeat the `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` sequence instead so the data are sorted for each repeat. But your are probably looking for something else?

Comment: Using your old code, a generator of my data can be `df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ev_type': np.random.choice(list("ABCDWK"), size=100,replace=True), 'ev_time': pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2016,1,1),freq='M', periods=100)})` . In these data I am looking for the sequence `A->B->C->D` appearing in order so I'm not interested in the sequences `A B D C D` nor `A B W C D`. Hope, it is more clear now.